# Как предопределить значение ComboBox с привязкой данных WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, binding, combobox

Есть WPF приложение с БД mssql. В общем есть страница с поставками и составом поставок. Прикрепляю скриншот чтобы было понятнее.[image: Страница]
При нажатии на поставку в верхней таблице в нижней отображаются все товары которые были в ней доставлены.

Также при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить в состав", открывается страница добавления состава поставки. Скриншот прикрепляю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема такова:
При нажатии на кнопку "добавить в состав" в странице добавление в ComboBox уже должен быть выбран и отображаться Номер поставки на который нажал пользователь. Я передаю на страницу редактирования с помощью аргумента выбранную поставку

```
gridDeliveries.SelectedItem as Delivery
```

То есть я знаю Id, знаю объект Delivery который выбран. Я пробовал по всякому задать значение для ComboBox, и SelectedValue и SelectedItem, и задать значение ID у объекта currentComposition который я создаю в базе при помощи этой страницы. ComboBox всё равно не имеет сразу это значение. Прикрепляю код.

```
<ComboBox Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate1}" 
     ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemContainerStyle1}" 
     Name="cmbDelivery"
     Width="300"
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
     DisplayMemberPath="ID"
     SelectedItem="{Binding Delivery}"
     SelectedValuePath="ID"
     Background="Transparent"
     BorderThickness="0">
</ComboBox>
```

---

```
private DeliveryComposition currentComposition = new DeliveryComposition();
        public DeliveryCompositionEdit(DeliveryComposition selectedComposition, Delivery selectedDelivery)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (selectedComposition != null)
            {       
                currentComposition = selectedComposition;
            }

            cmbProduct.ItemsSource = DeliveryView.contextDB.Product.ToList();
            cmbDelivery.ItemsSource = DeliveryView.contextDB.Delivery.ToList();

            DataContext = currentComposition;

            if (selectedDelivery != null)
            {
                cmbDelivery.SelectedValue = selectedDelivery.ID;
                currentComposition.ID_Delivery = selectedDelivery.ID;
                cmbDelivery.UpdateLayout();
            }

        }
```

Comment: У вас нет привязок, у вас есть каша из смеси всякого разного. Вот например это `cmbProduct.ItemsSource` у вас должно быть как `<ComboBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Products}">`, а это `cmbDelivery.SelectedValue` у вас должно быть как `<ComboBox SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedDelivery}">` `public SomeClass SelectedDelivery {get;set;} //еще реализация INPC` `SelectedDelivery = ...;`, ну и так далее, все это под общим `DataContext`. Сейчас вы просто дергаете UI контролы, не более, не менее..

Comment: Ну и да, вы нам не показали все нужное. Допустим что это такое `SelectedItem="{Binding Delivery}"`, где `Delivery`? Говорите о `gridDeliveries.SelectedItem as Delivery` а не показываете. `При нажатии на кнопку` - также не вижу кнопки и ее логики. Короче, вопрос не понятен.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (selectedDelivery != null)
{
    currentComposition.ID_Delivery = selectedDelivery.ID;
    cmbDelivery.UpdateLayout();
    cmbDelivery.SelectedItem = selectedDelivery;
}
```

Прописал следующий код в проверке, и теперь в ComboBox заранее установленное значение, в зависимости от выбранной поставки.